# Sandbox Code Execution Request Failed in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am getting "WebPart Error : Sandbox Code Execution Request Failed" on Sharepoint Online Cloud but very rarely.

I think it's because of not enough  resource has been allocated for this WebPart on 
Cloud. If yes then does anybody know how to justify it?

Thanks
Mitesh

Comment: I also faced the same problem. I could not see any solutions yet. In this url http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/20758.aspx  Jonis from Microsoft Online SharePoint Support says"we do not support custom development"